# Wordpress Facebook Album Plugin

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

I am currently using a Wordpress plugin called [Facebook Page Album](http://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-page-albums/) and below is the example code for showing the Facebook page albums list and I'm trying to convert it into Wordpress short code but I'm not sure how I should go about it as I'm not to familiar with Wordpress but I can only seem to use the `Return` statement so how would I go about using the following code with a short code.

```
    <?php
    $list = facebook_page_albums_get_album_list();
?>
    <ol class="album-list">
        <?php foreach ($list as $item) : ?>
            <?php
            if ($item['type'] != 'normal' || $item['name'] == 'Cover Photos') continue;
            ?>
            <li class="album">
                <?php if ($thumb = $item['cover_photo_data']):?>
                <div class="album-thumb">
                    <a href="<?php echo add_query_arg('id', $item['id']);?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $thumb['picture'];?>"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="album-info">
                    <h5><a href="<?php echo add_query_arg('id', $item['id']);?>"><?php echo $item['name'];?></a></h5>
                    <div class="counts">
                        <div class="photos-count"><?php echo $item['count'];?></div>
                        <?php if (!empty($thumb['comments'])) :?><div class="comments-count"><?php echo count($thumb['comments']['data']);?></div><?php endif;?>
                        <?php if (!empty($thumb['likes'])) :?><div class="likes-count"><?php echo count($thumb['likes']['data']);?></div><?php endif;?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </ol>
```

Comment: You should study the problem more and then ask something more specific. How about doing some reading here: [WordPress Codex: Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Comment: Ok after reading i'll just use the ob_start(); statement for now but thank you